# How to run the show method in routes.php

Tags: laravel, url, post, methods, routes

i write This routes in routes.php:

```
Route::post('reserves', 'Test\Api\Controllers\Reserves@index');
Route::post('reserves/{id}', 'Test\Api\Controllers\Reserves@show');
```

When my url is:

```
site.local/api/v1/reserves
```

the index method run currecly but when i use this url with userId parameter instead run show method the index method run, How can i fixed it?

```
site.local/api/v1/reserves // with userId parameters
```

Comment: You mean `site.local/api/v1/reserves/2` runs the `index` method? (Btw, there is no `routes.php` in vanilla Laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try get method instead of post method:

```
Route::get('reserves/{id}', 'Test\Api\Controllers\Reserves@show');
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you passing your userID parameters? In order to run `show` you should use the url:

```
site.local/api/v1/reserves/1 //or 1 replaced with any other id
```

If you are passing the userID as a `GET` or `POST` parameter the `show` method will not be executed.